# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Message:

Tags: c#

I have converted my 32 bit web Application into 64 bit and deployed it on a 64 bit machine all the modules are working fine but one.  **Why does this one throw this Exception?**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException  Message: Retrieving the
>   COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {494A8C73-FA00-43A7-9F1D-6DBF80EC2B63} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

What I understand is my code is calling a dll which is 32 bit, but when I checked in my 64x debug I found it there too.

Comment: You will need to find the 64-bit version of this COM component and install it.  With high odds that you won't find it, contact the owner of the COM component for support.

Answer (score 0):

You are running a 64bit application and most likely the DLL or OCX causing that exception is a 32 bit one. I think you cannot fix this unless you get a 64bit version of that file.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following link about [COMException (0x80040154) for Office interop on IIS 6 x64 system](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/555d3b94-d6ae-4a69-802a-8715d06873b6/comexception-0x80040154-for-office-interop-on-iis-6-x64-system)

It looks like there is currently no 64 bit version of the interop DLLs, which is probably to issue you are experiencing. Although the article refers to IIS, the issue is still the same.